# Is there anything wrong with having separate SSH keys for different virtual machines?

Tags: ssh, rhel, virtualbox, scp

Edit 2019-09-12: After everyone’s input. I’ve decided I need to research ssh key management so more. I will post outcome of research.

I am running RHEL-7.7 as a host hypervisor. I am running several VMs, each with their own particular function (pfsense, Intrusion Prevention Systems, Security Intrusion Events Managers). All machines are running Linux besides the pfsense router with BSD.

I want to have separate SSH keys make for each VM instance, if possible. This seems like it would be more secure, but is there a point where it would not be beneficial? Should I just share my 1 public key with all the VMs, or make separate keys?

Comment: Are you securing your private keys with passphrases?

Comment: Yes. I keep them all unique and in encrypted locations.

Comment: Encrypted how? And do you use an SSH agent? And agent forwarding?

Comment: I use gnome seahorse to manage. I have been looking at encryption with gpg.

Answer (score 2):

No, but it gets quite unmanageable when you have too many servers. At the company I work, I manage 350 single-handed. Usually, a relation one keypair per person (not necessarily an username) is a good choice. When that person goes away from the company/institution, you could write an Ansible playbook (for instance) that goes into each server and remove the respective public key from the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to setup your `.ssh/config` to use the right key for the right box, but that is something you do not need to do every day.

If one of your keys gets compromised, then you will only need to swap out the one key.

But on the other hand:  If one of your keys is compromised, then they likely all are, especially if you use passwordless keys.  So that could make swapping out the keys painful.

So depending on your security needs, you may want to mix and match a passwordless key and a couple of keys with good passwords.

Comment: At least with `ssh-agent`, you can add multiple keys to it, but I think there might have been some downsides to it at least with large numbers of keys. Something about the SSH server treating the key offers as login attempts, and then failing if the limit is reached before a correct key is found.

Comment: Yes, `MaxAuthTries` is the relevant parameter, and it (currently) defaults to six, so if you've got a dozen keys loaded in agent _and_ you cannot change `MaxAuthTries` on the server, you could fail to authenticate.

Comment: @PhilipCouling, by observation of behavior and by perusing the source code, yes.  Simple test: with `MaxAuthTries` at default six, and both password and pubkey authentication permitted, load four unusable (for a given server) keys in your agent, ssh to that server, and then see how many bad passwords you can type before you get the "too many authentication failures" message.  Use `ssh -vv` on the client side and observe authentication logs on the server side.

Comment: That seems an odd interpretation of the setting. I wonder why they chose non-attemps to count as authentication failures. I wonder if it was done to stop malatious clients accumilating long lists of compromised keys.

Answer (score -2):

My first question to you is "Why do you want to do that?" As the other answers pointed out, it can be a pain-in-the-neck to manage.

That being said, I have several environments here. Each environment has multiple VMs. Each environment have it's own set of SSH keys. Thus, you only get access to the environments for which you have the correct SSH keys.
That makes sense for us here. We do not have separate keys for each VM.

What does make sense (to me):
Database servers could have a key-pair. Which is used by all of the DBA/DBM folks.
Web server could have a (different) key-pair, which is used my the web maintainers, etc.
This is a great way to implement "least privileges" on your system.
$0.02

Comment: It is always a bad idea to share credentials between people. And with your setup iit seems even worse: if you want to revoke someone you have to invalidate the keys for everyone and reissue a new key that you distribute. You can have a single web-maintainer id, but it can be logged in by several people each using their own personal key.

Comment: So when you fire a DBA you have no way to revoke that DBAs rights without irritating the rest of the DBAs.

Comment: @user1133275: we have requirements to change our passwords & SSH keys every 6-months, when someone leaves the group, or is terminated. They are all used to the pain. However: We have "Privileged Users," so not ALL DBAs will have the ssh-keys. Yes, it's a PITA. It is what our customer requires.

Comment: That's a counterproductive requirement as is historicly the case with security; https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: Yes. Security isn't about productivity. It's about keeping out people who don't need to be there. Just like car-alarms & door locks are counterproductive, because you have to disarm/unlock them before you can do anything.

Comment: Thank you for the down vote without an explanation. I have adequately described my environment. I am not the SE. I had no say in it's design. I have to deal with it as is. I post my answer for others, as well as the OP, to learn from and use as an example for future readers.

Comment: This really sounds like a bad solution to a particular problem. If the issue was SSH key cycling policy, the right tool might have been a centralised SSH key management (eg over LDAP). Having one key per VM which has to be redistributed every 6 months is just a mess.  A malicious former employee can do a lot of damage in 6 months.